# Chart.js - Multiple JSON data object array [{x: Date, y: count}....] representing each dataset of the chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've been trying to implement a [Stacked Area Line Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/area/line-datasets.html) using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/area/line-datasets.html), which in turn uses multiple datasets as an input for each line graph.

Although I'am able to view the final stacked chart with the associated dataset, I can clearly notice that **y-axis data is falsely represented**(hover on data-point) w.r.t **x-axis** for each dataset, which is a major issue.

Major issues are:

1. x-axis and y-axis mapping issue for 2nd dataset chart onwards
2. x-axis values (dates) are repetitive and not in order - causes an abrupt display of chart

To be more clear, I need **dataset1[ {x: "2030*08-03", y: 8},{}...]** to precisely map keys x and y to the respective x-axis and y-axis of chart1, similary, **dataset2[ {x: "2030*08-10", y: 8},{}...]** mapping to the 2nd chart respectively and so on.

This is the sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/NishiBangar/pen/YzVoQYw?editors=1011) implementation replicating the issue.

Also, I'm adding the complete code snippet for a clear understanding.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
      green: {
        fill: 'rgb(0,128,0,0.2)',
        stroke: 'green',
      },
      grey: {
        fill: 'rgb(128,128,128, 0.2)',
          stroke: 'grey',
      },
      red: {
        fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        stroke: 'red',
      }
};

const data1 = [
        {x: "2030*08-03", y: 8},
        {x: "2030-08-04", y: 1},
        {x: "2030-08-08", y: 2},
        {x: "2030-08-09", y: 10},
        {x: "2030-08-10", y: 2},
        {x: "2030-08-12", y: 34} ];
const data2 = [
        {x: "2030-08-09", y: 1},
        {x: "2030-08-12", y: 12},
        {x: "2030-08-13", y: 3},
        {x: "2030-08-15", y: 3}
];
const data3 = [
        {x: "2030-08-06", y: 1},
        {x: "2030-08-09", y: 12},
        {x: "2030-08-10", y: 3},
        {x: "2030-08-12", y: 3} , ];


const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Data1",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.green.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.green.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.green.stroke,
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        data: data1,
      },
      {
        label: "Data2",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.grey.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.grey.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.grey.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.grey.stroke,
        data: data2,
      },
      {
        label: "Data3",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.red.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.red.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.red.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.red.stroke,
        data: data3,
       }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Status',
        padding: {
          top: 20,
          bottom: 15
        },
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 25
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 20,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 25
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          align: "center"
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Count",
          font: {
            weight: "bold",
            size: 20
          }
        }
      },
    },
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'x',
      yAxisKey: 'y'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is happening because chart.js automatically adds the labels if they are not there and doesnt care about ordering, you have 2 ways of fixing it, providing a labels array with all the labels in correct order already:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
  green: {
    fill: 'rgb(0,128,0,0.2)',
    stroke: 'green',
  },
  grey: {
    fill: 'rgb(128,128,128, 0.2)',
    stroke: 'grey',
  },
  red: {
    fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    stroke: 'red',
  }
};

const data1 = [{
    x: "2030-08-03",
    y: 8
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-04",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-08",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-09",
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-10",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-12",
    y: 34
  }
];
const data2 = [{
    x: "2030-08-09",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-12",
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-13",
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-15",
    y: 3
  }
];
const data3 = [{
    x: "2030-08-06",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-09",
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-10",
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-12",
    y: 3
  },
];


const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["2030-08-03", "2030-08-04", "2030-08-06", "2030-08-08", "2030-08-09", "2030-08-10", "2030-08-12", "2030-08-13", "2030-08-15"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Data1",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.green.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.green.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.green.stroke,
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        data: data1,
      },
      {
        label: "Data2",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.grey.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.grey.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.grey.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.grey.stroke,
        data: data2,
      },
      {
        label: "Data3",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.red.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.red.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.red.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.red.stroke,
        data: data3,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Status',
        padding: {
          top: 20,
          bottom: 15
        },
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 25
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 20,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 25
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          align: "center"
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Count",
          font: {
            weight: "bold",
            size: 20
          }
        }
      },
    },
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'x',
      yAxisKey: 'y'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/gOWNXKm?editors=1010

Or you can use a time axis:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
  green: {
    fill: 'rgb(0,128,0,0.2)',
    stroke: 'green',
  },
  grey: {
    fill: 'rgb(128,128,128, 0.2)',
    stroke: 'grey',
  },
  red: {
    fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    stroke: 'red',
  }
};

const data1 = [{
    x: "2030-08-03",
    y: 8
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-04",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-08",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-09",
    y: 10
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-10",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-12",
    y: 34
  }
];
const data2 = [{
    x: "2030-08-09",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-12",
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-13",
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-15",
    y: 3
  }
];
const data3 = [{
    x: "2030-08-06",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-09",
    y: 12
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-10",
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: "2030-08-12",
    y: 3
  },
];


const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: "Data1",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.green.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.green.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.green.stroke,
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        data: data1,
      },
      {
        label: "Data2",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.grey.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.grey.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.grey.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.grey.stroke,
        data: data2,
      },
      {
        label: "Data3",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: colors.red.fill,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors.red.stroke,
        borderColor: colors.red.stroke,
        pointHighlightStroke: colors.red.stroke,
        data: data3,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Status',
        padding: {
          top: 20,
          bottom: 15
        },
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 25
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 20,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 25
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
          align: "center"
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Count",
          font: {
            weight: "bold",
            size: 20
          }
        }
      },
    },
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'x',
      yAxisKey: 'y'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/GRmbOxN?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you Lee for the efforts. 

I've had the workaround implementation done the same way as your first approach: Providing all labels ordered in a Label array. Just wanted to learn about a better technique which automatically maps [{x,y}..{}] to x-axis and y-axis for each dataset defined. - Second approach.

However, in both the simulation implementation you've shared, only Data1 has a proper mapping of datapoints, whereas, Data2 and Data3 have false y-axis datapoints representation (you can notice in the tooltip).

It would be great  if you could look into it and let me know.

Thanks

Comment: They do represent correctly, because you tell chart.js to stack the y axis it stacks the line on top of the last one so if first point that is drawn has a value of 12 and the second a value of 3, the 3 gets drawn 3 spaces higher because you want it stacked so it draws it at the 15 mark, if you dont want this behaviour your should not use a stacked y axis

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Lee. Stacked - y-axis was not the result I'm expecting, so removed the "stacked y-axis" option and works perfectly as per my requirement. Thanks again.